# Rounding errors giving incorrect tesults in DFT?

Tags: c++, fft, rounding, dft

I have been beating my head against the wall on this DFT. It should print out: 8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 but instead I get 8 and then very very tiny numbers. Are these rounding errors? Is there anything I can do? My Radix2 FFT gives correct results, it seems silly a DFT could not also work.

I started with complex numbers so I know there is a good bit missing, I tried to strip it down to illustrate the problem.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cassert>

#define SIZE 8
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846

void fft(const double src[], double dst[], const unsigned int n) 
{
    for(int i=0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        const double ph = -(2*M_PI) / n;
        const int gid = i;

        double res = 0.0f;
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {

            double t = src[k];

            const double val = ph * k * gid;
            double cs = cos(val);
            double sn = sin(val);

            res += ((t * cs) - (t * sn));
            int a = 1;
        }

        dst[i] = res;
        std::cout << dst[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    double array1[SIZE];
    double array2[SIZE];

    for(int i=0; i < SIZE; i++){
        array1[i] = 1;
        array2[i] = 0;
    }

    fft(array1, array2, SIZE);

    return 666;
}
```

Comment: How tiny are the tiny numbers ?

Comment: @PaulR On the order of 1e-16

Comment: That sounds about right - 16 or 17 decimal places is around the limit for double precision. Note that you should really use M_PI from <cmath> rather than rolling your own but I don't think it makes much difference in this case.

Comment: Yeah it's really irritating. I can fix the output using 

    std::cout.setf ( std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield )

but that only fixes the display. On large datasets the cumulative error actually adds up to something meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

An FFT can actually produce more accurate results than a straight DFT calculation, as the fewer arithmetic ops usually allow fewer opportunities for arithmetic quantization errors to accumulate.  There's a paper by one of the FFTW authors on this topic.

Since the DFT/FFT deal with a transcendental basis function, the results will never (except perhaps in a few special cases, or by lucky accident) be exactly correct using any non-symbolic and finite computer number format.  So values very close (within a few LSB) to zero should simply be ignored as noise, or considered to be the same as zero.

Comment: Yeah right now I am doing:

    int tmp = res*100;
    dst[i] = tmp /100.0f;

is there something more efficient? I also have a radix 2 FFT but they only work on 2^N size data sets which doesn't do me much good.